# R regex match pattern and replace with dynamic value

Tags: regex, r, replace, match

In R, I need to come up with a way to extract from the following data:

```
Using Notifications API: Strategy ON_TARGET:LookForward Ratio: 0.25 Num of hours back: 6 Rpr Cfg--> FP: 9.02 CP: 18.04 MSR: 0.51 MPR: 0.49 TTRR: 0.51. RepricingMethod_ReachTopRankOnTarget:  Sampling info: Dilutions: 2_1_1_7_4_2-AKQSGIBQINE7B, 1_1_1_3_4_2-A2TBTG410J2ORU, 1_1_1_5_4_2-AQNACJEM8PUJ1, 1_1_1_6_4_2-A2R0FX412W1BDT, 1_1_1_6_4_2-A1TFBK3C7LO58P, 1_1_1_4_4_2-A1WMYU489BEYM4, 1_1_1_7_3_2-A3G2RBEZBLAJ53, 1_1_1_5_4_2-A2RFSIF56F6W5J, 1_1_1_6_4_2-AAL7E530K3IX2, 1_1_1_7_4_2-AFAGM2K2OIRAD, 1_1_1_6_4_2-APRB74G8QOR1X, 1_1_1_5_3_2-A24POLY6RKLSW7, 1_1_1_5_4_2-A18IJX3G7FD5MC, 1_1_1_5_3_2-A1UEW3GW612BDQ, 1_1_1_7_4_2-A2G88111572J8M, 1_1_1_4_4_2-A2IKHPELK48TV7, 1_1_1_7_4_2-A79CLRHOQ3NF4, Additions: None.New TTR: 0.9  Merchant is not top ranked, merchant group known (2_1_1_7_4_2-AKQSGIBQINE7B), top ranked group known (2_1_1_7_4_2-ATVPDKIKX0DER), taking prices of 1 groups above/equal merchant group as reference. Lowest landing price within these groups is 9.19 . Initially suggested change: 0.0, change determined upon historical analysis: 0.0 with significance of 1.0, prediction for top rank: false, state trace: -_S6_S8- HWP: null- LLP: 9.02 Reducing price obtained by history to 8.91. Modification: New price lower than floor price, reset to floor price. Target optimization: Current top rank ratio is 0.0, different optimal ratio was not found.
```

the numeric value that appears after the pattern 'TTRR:' and ends with a dot (.). In the above example the value returned should be 0.51.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a basic substitution here.

```
sub('.*TTRR:\\s*([0-9.]+)\\..*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "0.51"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex.

```
"TTRR:\\s*\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=\\.)"
```

[\K](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dH4cL3/7)

```
> x <- "Using Notifications API: Strategy ON_TARGET:LookForward Ratio: 0.25 Num of hours back: 6 Rpr Cfg--> FP: 9.02 CP: 18.04 MSR: 0.51 MPR: 0.49 TTRR: 0.51. RepricingMethod_ReachTopRankOnTarget:  Sampling info: Dilutions: 2_1_1_7_4_2-AKQSGIBQINE7B, 1_1_1_3_4_2-A2TBTG410J2ORU, 1_1_1_5_4_2-AQNACJEM8PUJ1, 1_1_1_6_4_2-A2R0FX412W1BDT, 1_1_1_6_4_2-A1TFBK3C7LO58P, 1_1_1_4_4_2-A1WMYU489BEYM4, 1_1_1_7_3_2-A3G2RBEZBLAJ53, 1_1_1_5_4_2-A2RFSIF56F6W5J, 1_1_1_6_4_2-AAL7E530K3IX2, 1_1_1_7_4_2-AFAGM2K2OIRAD, 1_1_1_6_4_2-APRB74G8QOR1X, 1_1_1_5_3_2-A24POLY6RKLSW7, 1_1_1_5_4_2-A18IJX3G7FD5MC, 1_1_1_5_3_2-A1UEW3GW612BDQ, 1_1_1_7_4_2-A2G88111572J8M, 1_1_1_4_4_2-A2IKHPELK48TV7, 1_1_1_7_4_2-A79CLRHOQ3NF4, Additions: None.New TTR: 0.9  Merchant is not top ranked, merchant group known (2_1_1_7_4_2-AKQSGIBQINE7B), top ranked group known (2_1_1_7_4_2-ATVPDKIKX0DER), taking prices of 1 groups above/equal merchant group as reference. Lowest landing price within these groups is 9.19 . Initially suggested change: 0.0, change determined upon historical analysis: 0.0 with significance of 1.0, prediction for top rank: false, state trace: -_S6_S8- HWP: null- LLP: 9.02 Reducing price obtained by history to 8.91. Modification: New price lower than floor price, reset to floor price. Target optimization: Current top rank ratio is 0.0, different optimal ratio was not found."
> m <- gregexpr("TTRR:\\s*\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?=\\.)", x, perl=TRUE)
> regmatches(x, m)
[[1]]
[1] "0.51"
```

**OR**

```
> gsub("TTRR:\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))|.", "\\1", x)
[1] "0.51"
> gsub("TTRR:\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))\\.|.", "\\1", x)
[1] "0.51"
```

Comment: works well. Thanks for the quick reply. Since it's quite a long expression could you please explain what each part does or maybe you have a good source of documentation for that?